# How to make checkbox tree of directory in pyqt6?

Tags: pyqt

I use Python and pyqt6. I created the interface in qt designer.

I need to make an element where I can open a directory and get a menu that looks like a directory tree, but with checkboxes next to each element so that I can check and get only the selected one.
An example of such a menu can be seen in µTorrent or qBittorrent, in the menu for selecting which files you want to download. I need the same menu.

Im new in Python and this is my first time using these libraries, I tried to find something similar on the Internet, but I couldn’t find anything